# Prove that if $M$ is a simple $k[x_1,...,x_m]$-module, then the dimension of $M$ over $k$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $k$ be a field and let $R=k[x_1,...,x_m]$ be the polynomial ring in $m$ indeterminates. Prove that if $M$ is a simple $R$-module, then the dimension of $M$ over $k$ is finite.

I think since $M$ is simple we have $M=Rm$ for some $m\in M$ and if $Ann(m)=I$ in $R$ then $M\cong R/I$ and since $R$ is noetherian $I$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, but how we can conclude the statement from this? Any help would be great.

Comment: The ideal $I$ must be maximal - correct?  So https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma applies. By the way,  $M = Rm$, for any (and not 'some') $m\not = 0$.

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $M$ is simple we have $M=R/\mathfrak m$ where $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. But $R/\mathfrak m$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, and by [Zariski's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma) it is a finite field extension of $k$.